# How do I get the Scene from a FXViewPart in a Eclipse RCP Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx-2, eclipse-rcp

I currently have an eclipse rcp project where the main viewpart is using JavaFx via the FXViewPart. I want to be able to access the contents of the scene from an eclipse rcp command. I am able to access the view part by its id but not sure how to grab its scene.

Code Snippet of the Command:

```
FXViewPart view = (FXViewPart) page.findView("com.interpro.emmeclipse.views.PageBuilderPart");
```

The ViewPart:

```
public class PageBuilderPart extends FXViewPart {

@Override
protected Scene createFxScene() {
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    final AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

    engine.load("file:///Development/EMM/EMMEclipse/src/com/interpro/emmeclipse/html/PageCreator.html");


    final IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    if (activeEditor != null) {
        final IDocument doc = (IDocument) activeEditor.getAdapter(IDocument.class);
        if(doc != null)
            System.out.println(doc.get());
    }

    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(webView, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(webView, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(webView, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(webView, 0.0);
    root.getChildren().addAll(webView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    return scene;
}

@Override
protected void setFxFocus() {
}
```

}

Ultimately I want to grab the webview from the command class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish it somewhere yourself e.g.

```
public PageBuilderPart extends FXViewPart implements FXSceneProvider {
   private Scene s;

   public Scene getScene() {
     return s;
   }
}

public interface FXSceneProvider {
    public Scene getScene();
}
```

and use it

```
 FXSceneProvider view = (FXSceneProvider) page.findView("com.interpro.emmeclipse.views.PageBuilderPart");
```

Anyways I'm not sure this is the right philosophie in Eclipse you should execute the command and the your part should have registered itself as a CommandListener and process the result of the command.